# Mac vs. iOS safari src path requirements for playing html5 videos?

Tags: ios, html, google-chrome, html5-video

I'm having trouble understanding why videos i have stored on my server can't be played on iOS Safari but can be played on Mac Safari. I took these videos from [this page](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/videojs-html5-video-player-for-wordpress/installation/).

To show you what I mean, the following works on Mac and iOS Safari:

```
<video src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4"></video>
```

Whereas this only works on Mac but **not** iOS Safari:

```
<video src="http://mysite.com/oceans-clip.mp4" ></video>
```

I'm totally confused since they are the same exact videos. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely because you have a self signed certificate for SSL. I ran into the same problem. iOS doesnt play video html from self signed certs.

Comment: -@Gregory, thanks! that is a really weird finding. You prompted me to find this which references this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660189/cannot-view-quicktime-movies-over-https-in-safari-or-uiwebview

Answer (score 1):

According to the official [Safari Developper Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW1), you should add "controls"

```
<video src="http://mysite.com/oceans-clip.mp4" controls ></video>
```

Comment: no luck Soader03, thanks for the suggestion but this didn't fix the problem, it still attempts to play (goes to fullscreen) but as before i get multiple popups each saying "This movie could not be played."

Comment: I think its something with my server cause it happens regardless of how the video is controlled (i.e., using JS or default HTML controls)

Comment: Have you tried it with Safari for Windows / Mac? Maybe it's a browser specific problem

Comment: hi Soader3, yes I tried Safari for Mac, it works there and firefox too, i think it my be something with my live mysite.com server, its set up as `https://` and not `http://` but maybe the security settings aren't  quite right, i didn't set up the `https://` myself so not sure,

Comment: Hmmm don't know neither... Never experienced that issue

Comment: hmm, maybe its a iOS4 vs iOS5 difference since my Mac has Safari5 but my iPhone is iOS4.3 (so Safari would be version4 too?)

Comment: Is your site online? I could give a try with my iPhone on iOS 5.1

Comment: just to clarify, its not something with `https://` because because I can get the video to play on `https://mysite.com` on all laptop browsers, its just it wont play on iOS safari

Comment: Hmm I see the first frame of the video with a symbol saying it can't play the video. Maybe, yes, the server is not well configured or the video is not in a correct format for the iOS playback.

Comment: hi Soader03, the video is in the correct format since it plays on laptop browsers and is the same exact video as `src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4"`, It must be a server issue, wow this is weird

Comment: The fact that the video plays on a laptop doesn't mean it can play on iOS. iOS need a specific encoding for playing it. Did you encoded the video yourself? The video must be MPEG-4 video (Baseline profile) and QuickTime movies encoded with H.264 video (Baseline profile) and one of the supported audio types.

Comment: I didn't do anything to the encoding, i just downloaded the video from zencoder.com and uploaded to mysite.com. What's weird is that the video plays on iOS safari if the src is set to `http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4` but **NOT** if the src is set to  `http://mysite.com/oceans-clip.mp4`

Comment: Oh, I see. Don't know what else to try to help you. Sorry dude

Comment: thanks anyway, seems like there will be simple fix at some point, i'll keep thinking about it, thanks for trying!

Answer (score 1):

just a suggestion but are the mime types properly configured on your server? some browsers are pickier than other with mime types...

If you go to an URL of the video file in Firefox and use an extension like livehttpheaders you should be able to see which mime type the file is sent as, it will probably need to be corrected in your config - google should tell you how to do this. :-)

Comment: hi Neil, hmm i checked my mime.types file and it is the same on my mac local server as it is on mysite.com server. The fact that the video plays if served from zencoder.com but not mysite.com makes me think there is something more obscure going on here.