# MP4 Videos on website embed with html5 does not play on iOS

Tags: ios, html, ffmpeg, mp4

So I have a couple of videos on my website that I shot using the iPhone 4 and then converted to mp4, webm and ogg, so that I can use them with html5. Thing is, the video does not play at all on the 4 iOS devices that I tested and neither on Chrome for Android.

The Chrome issue could be because some of the mp4 are actually m4v files, but still after encoding with handbrake a video to the iphone 4 presset and in mp4 format, it still does not play.

What happens, you ask? Well, it shows the play button crossed out with a diagonal bar, the debug console on Safari does not show any message untill I try to access the video directly. Then it says: QuickTime Movie could not be played.

What can I do? I have been trying to encode with ffmpeg, have tried a handful of different solutions, some even found here on stackoverlow, but to no avail. The videos do get shorter, both in display size and MBs, but nothing works to fix the issue at hand.

I've been trying to get this corrected for a couple of weeks now. Any help and/or suggestions are welcome.

Thank you.

By the way, all the videos are on a registred users section of the website, but I have one for debugin on the main page, so feel free to test.

https://sidnerwebsite.sytes.net

Comment: MP4 is just a container format. It looks like the video is encoded in the wrong format.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660189/cannot-view-quicktime-movies-over-https-in-safari-or-uiwebview

Comment: I encoded it in h.254 video and audio AAC, just like Apple specifies. Like I said, I used handbrake's iphone 4 preset and I've used this ffmpeg command:


ffmpeg -i IMG_2159.MOV -s 320x240 -r 30000/1001 -b 200k -bt 240k -vcodec libx264 -vpre slower -vpre baseline -coder 0 -bf 0 -refs 1 -flags2 -wpred-dct8x8 -level 30 -maxrate 10M -bufsize 10M -acodec libfaac -ac 2 -ar 48000 -ab 192k output.mp4

Comment: So according to mark4o's link, the problem is me not having an intermediate certificate... Could it be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the issue is caused by the iOS' need of an Intermediate Certificate trusted by the iOS to play videos through an SSL connection. After disabling the re-routing of the website to its ssl counterpart, the videos display correctly on iOS.