# html Video tag not working in ios with blazor wasm app

Tags: html, ios, safari, html5-video, blazor-webassembly

I have a html video that I want to play on the homepage, this is copied from the dev tools on a (working) chrome browser.

```html
        <div class="VidContainer">
            <video autoplay muted loop playsinline poster="https://rafflegames.blob.core.windows.net/publicvideos/BeAWinner.jpg">
                <source src="https://rafflegames.blob.core.windows.net/publicvideos/BeAWinner.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
        </div>
```

It also works on a Mac using Chrome but not Safari, so I guess this is some kind of Apple foible.

I did see this question here: [MP4 Videos on website embed with html5 does not play on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195581/mp4-videos-on-website-embed-with-html5-does-not-play-on-ios) ... but I don't really understand how to create the intermediate certificates, so I've tried also moving the 'source' to be local to the server so it isn't going externally for it.  That didnt solve it.

I just want it to play nice like it does on everything else. Any thoughts? Is this a Blazor WASM specific thing or is Safari just a bit broken/awkward?

**EDIT - MORE INFO**
This is starting to feel more like a Blazor issue. The reason I thnk this is that to try to eliminate Blazor (as the issue), I put the  tag in the 'app' loading section of the index.html. As you may be aware, this is overloaded by the 'Blazor' app.
Trying this, IT WORKED, during the load cycle, however, once Blazor had kicked in the video on the start page was static (ie. the Poster was displayed).

Comment: Your shown code isn't doing any Blazor WASM specific things. The code should work (as shown) on a Mac and also on iOS. Did you test your shown code (no WASM etc) using Safari? Maybe explain what the Blazor/WASM part does regarding the video file, then maybe someone can explain the why, and also how to make it play on iOS.

Comment: You're right... I'm not doing anything Blazor specific there, and it works fine on Chrome on all platforms... apparently.

Comment: OK. The reason I asked for a brief explanation of what the WASM part does is because sometimes such code involves using a **sharedArray** which is/was generally not supported on any mobile device OS (although Android now does since 2022).  You say it works on Chrome on all platforms (assuming this also means Android) so now I can't think what else it could be. The WASM / Blazor part is too mysterious for guesstimates to even begin. Your MP4 file seems fine (did you confirm if a `<video>` tag can play it? Give it your shown MP4 file path).

Comment: Sorry, I went away for a week and the place I went to had terrible internet...  
Yes, if you can see the 'code snippet' above, you can run it. I honestly don't think its a Blazor thing now, because I am hearing of all sorts of issues from elsewhere as well, even on a friends Wordpress site, that works cos he uses Chrome all the time on his mac, he realised it doesn't on Mac/Safari... Thanks for your help..