# Why video from HTTPS URL will not play on iOS web browser?

Tags: ios, http, video, browser, https

Could someone explain or help me understand why this [HTTPS video link](https://mediastreamer.doit.wisc.edu/uwli-ltc/sandbox/ethansandbox/VideoWall/assets/videos/LesMiserables.mp4) **does not play** on iPad and iPhone's web browser?

However, this [HTTP link](http://mediastreamer.doit.wisc.edu/uwli-ltc/sandbox/ethansandbox/VideoWall/assets/videos/LesMiserables.mp4) **does play** on iPad and iPhone's web browser.

Both are pointing to the same video file on the same web server. They're just alias web links.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a valid Intermediate Certificate installed on the server.

More about that: [Cannot view Quicktime movies over HTTPS in Safari or UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660189/cannot-view-quicktime-movies-over-https-in-safari-or-uiwebview)

Comment: My sever does have an intermediate certificate installed and it is installed correctly. It still will not work. SSL checker confirmed it (http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=mediastreamer.doit.wisc.edu)