# HTML5 video can not play in iPhone safari browser

Tags: html, video, https, safari

I have a html page with video tag,it work fine in every browser when use http,but if the website switch to https,the video can't play in iPhone safari browser,  anyone ever seen this and know if there are ways around it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660189/cannot-view-quicktime-movies-over-https-in-safari-or-uiwebview) link for the same question or this [apple forum link](https://devforums.apple.com/message/361209#361209) if you have devkit. 
You must have a valid Intermediate Certificate installed on the server. It is not enough to have only the server certificate installed.

Comment: If this question is a duplicate (and it looks like it is), you should have marked it as a duplicate, and/or posted the link to the original one as a comment.

Comment: Sorry new here! Ill will get better in the future!

Comment: No problem. We've all been there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem doesn't lie with the video, protocol, or the player. It has something to do with the SSL certificate. Have a look [here](http://www.neanderthal-technology.com/2012/04/ipad-video-not-working-over-https/) - it describes a similar problem you're experiencing, but on the iPad.