# Safari will not play mp4 over HTTPS

Tags: html, https, safari, mp4

I have a file, sample.html, which contains only the following code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <video width="600" autoplay loop poster="placeholder.jpg">
    <source src="sample.mp4" />
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

The mp4 file referenced is the one downloaded from Apple: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1425

When I use Safari to access my page via http://myserver.com/sample.html the video plays without problem.

When I use Safari to access my page via https://myserver.com/sample.html only the placeholder image is displayed.

Details
Safari 7.0.6
Mac OS X 10.9.4

I have used http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html to check that SSL is correctly configured for my domain and it reports no problems.

How can I make the video play in Safari when accessed over https?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and solved it by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660189/cannot-view-quicktime-movies-over-https-in-safari-or-uiwebview). You need a valid certificate authority for your webserver certificate, otherwise Safari won't play videos called via https.