# Appcelerator Videoplayer Can't Play From HTTPS

Tags: video, https, titanium, appcelerator, video-player

I'm trying to make a videoplayer in Appcelerator. When I provide a regular (HTTP) link, it plays well. But when I want to play a video from an HTTPS source, it fails.

Here is a sample code block:

```
var vidWin = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    title : 'Video View Demo',
    backgroundColor : '#fff'
});

var videoPlayer = Titanium.Media.createVideoPlayer({
    top : 2,
    autoplay : true,
    backgroundColor : 'blue',
    height : 300,
    width : 300,
    mediaControlStyle : Titanium.Media.VIDEO_CONTROL_DEFAULT,
    scalingMode : Titanium.Media.VIDEO_SCALING_ASPECT_FIT
});

videoPlayer.url = 'https://www.musttechnews.com/11eylul.mp4';
vidWin.add(videoPlayer);
vidWin.open();
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: do you have any error message? Working fine for me on Android, 7.1.0.GA

Comment: Unfortunately, no... I'm working on iOS. Could it be an iOS-specific permission problem, or what?

Comment: I would say it is a codec problem. I can't play the video in Safari. Neither with or without https

Comment: It seems that's a Cloudflare problem. Safari can't play Cloudflare-enabled sites' videos. The situation became out of the topic.

Comment: I see. Please add this as an answer and mark it so this is solved in case someone else finds it

Comment: voting to close as too broad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I realized, this is a really different problem. That is a certificate problem caused by Safari. Check following links for details:

[Safari will not play mp4 over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25709713/safari-will-not-play-mp4-over-https?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/