# iOS 9 Safari can't play MP4 over SSL

Tags: ios, ssl, video, safari

I am trying to get a MP4 file played on iOS 9 Safari on an iPad 3.  The MP4 file was hosted on a Windows 2008 R2 server with TLS 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2 turned on. No matter how I configured the server with IIS Crypto, it seems that Safari could not play it over HTTPS but it can just be played only on HTTP.  I did some researches and found [Cannot view Quicktime movies over HTTPS in Safari or UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660189/cannot-view-quicktime-movies-over-https-in-safari-or-uiwebview). I have make sure the intermediate certificate was installed on the server but still can't get the MP4 file played.  Any advice will be highly appreciated, thanks.